# In Win10 is there a fool proof way of discovering which App is displaying a given pop-up?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, task-manager, popups

I'm working on re-purposing a Win10 laptop that has some security feature whereby all USB disks have to be approved and registered. I cannot remove that feature because I cannot see which app, service or setting is doing it.

When I plug in a USB disk I get a pop-up saying the disk is not registered and cannot be used etc. The pop-up just sits there. I open Task Manager and it just has those zillion processes running. None of their names or resource usage patterns tips me off as the process that is displaying that pop-up. If I press alt-tab it just shows that pop-up as one of the running Apps but no indication of the name or location of any of the Apps.

If there's visibly a Window opened up on your desktop is there a way to track down which App owns or opened that Window?  BTW it's not a browser or browser notification.  It has to be some kind of background security SW.

A friend of mine was gifted her work laptop when she got laid off with the caveat that it was strictly as is. The thing is like Fort Knox and I've been unraveling all their security stuff. But I cannot find the origin or enforcer of this USB limitation.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), there is an icon in the toolbar named `Find Window's process`, you drag it over the window or dialog in question and it shows which process owns that window.

Comment: Wow that tool looks great! I don't know how I hadn't heard of it earlier. That said. It says "Unable to find the owning ..." when I drag that round icon over the pop-up in question. (Just my luck.) But I tested this out on a few more windows and it works great.

Comment: This works for most windows, so it is a good answer.