# In Win10 can anyone identify a security package that forces me to register all USB storage devices with a business network?

Tags: windows-10, security, usb-storage

I'm trying to repurpose a Win10 business laptop from a large organization. A friend was gifted it when she was layed off but it was as is.  I removed it from their network, unraveled their security measures, etc. But there is one thing left that I cannot seem to find.

Whenever I plug in a USB storage device I get a pop-up saying that I cannot use that device until it is approved by their organization and then encrypted.  I can view the files on the device, but any attempts to write data failed and that pop-up is displayed again.  This happens even in Safe Mode. The only logo on the pop-up is the name of the organization that gave me the laptop (which is not a SW company).  Here's what I've done to try to find out who this is:

[image]

1. I booted in Safe Mode and looked thru task manager, then plugged in the USB device and checked again.  I could not find any new tasks / processes.
2. I just inspected everything running in Task Manager and could not find anything with a name about USB security or any SW package that looks like it's from a security company.
3. I used [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to ID the pop-up window, but that said it is unknown.
4. I went thru all the Apps in Control Panel - Programs and Features and found no Apps that seem to be from a security company
5. I went into the Group Policy Editor and allowed access to USB Storage Devices.

Then later:

1. Followed a procedure to edit registry settings to allow write access to Mass Storage Devices.
2. Checked the System Event Log but no one logged anything right at the times I got that pop-up and there was nothing about denying write access to a USB drive.
3. Attempted to copy a file using an elevated CMD prompt but it only said "access denied" and opened that same pop-up with no further information.
4. Used Process Explorer to close all non-Windows and non-MS Apps, but the behavior persisted.
5. Did the Windows reinstall from USB media (It let's me read USB files) that kind that allows you to Keep Files and Apps. The reinstall succeeded but the USB security restriction remained.

Also the Control Panel - Bitlocker setting for external USB storage is grayed out as if it's being overridden by another setting.  Here the image:

[image]

Does anyone recognize this kind of pop-up or have any good guesses as to who it may belong to?  Does anyone have any suggestions beyond what I've already tried that may give me a clue as to who is doing this?

I'll reference [an earlier question that I asked about ID-ing pop-ups](https://superuser.com/a/1610729/129638). But that answer did not work for me so now I'm asking if anyone can help me using any strategy at all.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to download a copy of Windows direct from Microsoft and just wipe the machine to get rid of everything to do with the company? You'll obviously need to create the install USB on a different machine...

Comment: @Mokubai. Yeah I may have to resort to that. The laptop has some pretty cool SW on it that was licensed individually that she'd be able to keep if I could save the existing Win10 image. Also it leaves the question is simply reinstalling the OS professional service or something her son could have done for her?

Comment: As long as the firmware doesn't have a password on it then wiping it can be as easy as going in and making sure that boot from USB is enabled. If it does have a password then you'd have to contact the IT people responsible. Other than that it is simply booting the installer, deleting existing partitions and letting the installer go. The machine should (hopefully) have a digital entitlement for a licence so should simply skip entering a key, but that's not 100% guaranteed. I'd be tempted to use clonezilla to back it up before wiping.

Comment: Alternatively you might be able to do a clean install from **Start -> Settings -> Update & Security -> Recovery** or boot from USB from that area.

Comment: There is an easy alternative for identifying the process the popup comes from: Just use ProcessExplorer to kill every process one-by-one. When the dialog disappears you got it. But before you do so I would use Autoruns and disable all non-Microsoft and unverified services.

Comment: Hi Mokubai, Thx, now I tried that reinstall Keeping Apps and Data, but it also kept this security problem.

Comment: Hi Robert, Good suggestion.  I tried it.  That led me to figure out that the pop-up is just an HTML file and whoever puts it there stops owning it after they put it there.  But I used your plan to just stop all no Win and MS processes, but even after stopping all those the behavior persists.